# How to implement the social sharing in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to implement the social sharing feature of the articles which have been posted in my rails app. I tried following the documentation of **gem 'social-share-button'** where the following steps were followed :

step 1: Add //= require rails-social-share-button in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

step 2: Add *= require rails-social-share-button in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

step 3: use the **social_share_button_tag** helper method in views to display the social share buttons. *for e.g* `= rails_social_share_button_tag('Share to Facebook', url: article_path(@article), desc: @article.content)`

**Error**: 
undefined method `rails_social_share_button_tag' for #<#:0x00005574ff28ec30>

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` and did you restart the server after adding the gem?

Comment: yes, I did bundle, install and restart the server

Comment: The error message disappeared after I replaced the line `rails_social_share_button_tag` with `social_share_button_tag`. However, I am not being able to see any buttons in the view

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a step or two from the gem's readme. The order of the instructions in the readme is a little misleading. Did you run `rails generate rails_social_share_button:install`? You may also want to check the contents of the "config/initializers/rails_social_share_button.rb" file after you've run that generator.

Alternatively, you may want to use the ["social-share-button"](https://rubygems.org/gems/social-share-button/) gem. It looks like the one you're using, with its longer name, is a copy of everything in shorter-named "social-share-button" gem. Also it looks like the "social-share-button" gem has been around longer and is better maintained, as it already includes one bugfix that the gem you're using does not. I'd recommend first switching gems and then running `bundle install`. After switching gems, you should run the generator command listed in [the readme for social-share-button](https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button/blob/master/README.md), check the config file as the readme recommends, and then update your views accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I had already followed the steps you are suggesting me to do

Comment: I used the other gem **shareable** instead